# Including JSTL taglib in Apache Tiles template

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tiles

I am using Apache Tiles, in my small Spring MVC project, and I use JSTL tags to display data in my application views. But whenever I load any page (view) I can't see any data displayed, moreover I don't see the include tag line in top of the page, so can someone please check my configuration and code files below and tell me what I am missing? Note: I don't get any error...simply nothing is displayed as if the JSTL tag is never included.

1. Tiles.xml

> ```
> <tiles-definitions>
>
> <definition name="mainLayout" template="/WEB-INF/views/layout.jsp">
> <put-attribute name="title" value="Test Company" />
> <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" />
> <put-attribute name="navigation" value="" />
> <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
> <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" />
> </definition>
>
> <definition name="mainPage" extends="mainLayout"">
> <put-attribute name="title" value="Home" /> 
> <put-attribute name="header" value="" />
> <put-attribute name="navigation" value="" />
> <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
> <put-attribute name="footer" value="" />
> </definition>
>
> </tiles-definitions>
> ```

1. Layout.jsp

<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            
            
   

  /resources/css/style.css">
  
  /resources/jq/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">

```
    <div id="sidebar">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="navigation" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
```

1. home.jsp

   ```
   <div id="main">
       <div class="section">

                 <c:forEach var="country" items="${countriesList}">
           <div class="table_row">                     
          <div class="cell important">${country.id}</div>
          <div class="cell">${country.countryName}</div>
                   </div>
                 </c:forEach>

       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. CountryController.java

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "admin/countries")
   public String listCountries(HttpServletRequest request,Locale locale, Model model){
     model.addAttribute("countriesList", icountryservice.getAllCountries());
     return "mainPage";
   }
   ```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here, and how I can get JSTL tags to work again?

Thanks for your time

NOTE: I tried to paste the content of layout.jsp but I can't paste it here as code or anything...any idea how to paste html code here?

Comment: getting JSTL to work in your jsps has nothing to do with tiles or spring.

Comment: @mck then how I can make it work?

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>